# TF Error: Lookup would requrie extrapolation into the future

Tags: slam, navigation, ros-kinetic, jackal, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm running rtabmap on a jackal robot with bumblebee2 stereo camera on ros-kinetic. I get the following error when trying to view pointcloud2 topic in rviz:

```
Transform [sender=unknown_publisher] For frame [front_camera_optical]: No transform to fixed frame [map]. TF error: [Lookup would require extrapolation into the future. Requested time 1533228746.513341601 but the latest data is at time 1533228664.878277882, when looking up transform from frame [front_camera_optical] to frame [map]]
```

When I view the tf tree [link text](https://imgur.com/a/7e3s1p2) I see that i'm getting -0.086 sec old from the map broadcast by rtabmap.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/299390/tf-error:-lookup-would-requrie-extrapolation-into-the-future/) by [asabet](https://answers.ros.org/users/35904/asabet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2018-08-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-08-01**:
Can you please update your question with a copy and paste of the error instead of linking to an image? Text from images isn't searchable and people cannot copy and paste the text from it.

**Comment by [asabet](https://answers.ros.org/users/35904/asabet/) on 2018-08-02**:
Thanks for the feedback! Any ideas on what the issue could be?

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-08-02**:
It's most likely a [network problem](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup). Take a look at that page and look for other solutions on this site, it's a pretty common problem that's been asked many times.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-08-02**:
If you go through that page and try those solutions and are still having issues go ahead and please update your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is often caused by either of the following issues:

- Running nodes on more than one host when the host's clocks are not synchronized closely enough. You need to run NTP on each host, to synchronize their clocks with a network server, or set the times manually upon boot, or have one machine synch from another.
- Mixing messages played back a bag file and "live" messages from running nodes.

(There are probably more ways to have this happen, but those two have been most common for me.)

ROS relies on each host keeping track of the current time. If you don't have a battery-backed-up clock you'll have to either have network connectivity for NTP or synchronize the clocks in some other way.

---

Originally posted by [Mark Rose](https://answers.ros.org/users/27558/mark-rose/) with karma: 1563 on 2018-08-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3